# Set variable in Matlab Dataset array to a single value

Tags: matlab, syntax

Let's say I have a dataset array (from the statistics toolbox):

```
>> myds
myds = 
    Observation    SheepCount
    1              88        
    2               2        
    3              14        
    4              12        
    5              40
```

I'm putting together data from various sources, so I'd like to set 'Location' to be 4 in all of these observations, before I `vertcat` this dataset together with others.  In a normal matrix, you'd say `myds(:, 3) = 4`, which would broadcast the 4 into all of the spaces in the matrix.

Is there a way to do that on a dataset without using `repmat`?

Things I've tried that don't work:

```
myds(:, 'Location') = 4
myds(:).Location = 4
myds.Location(:) = 4
myds.Location = 4
```

Things that work:

```
myds.Location = 4; myds.Location(:) = 4; % have to run both
myds.Location = repmat(4, length(myds), 1);
```

<strike>So, do I have to get over my aversion to `repmat`?  Thanks.</strike>

**edit**: I guess what I actually want is to avoid specifying the dimensions of the array of 4's.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ones` instead of `repmat`.

```
myds.Location=4*ones(1,5);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice, but in anything but a trivial case it'll still have to be `4*ones(length(myds),1)`, which is still kinda ugly.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think it can be done with datasets, although it works perfectly fine with arrays. Your first suggestion is perhaps the simplest. Personally, I would say `myds.Location=4*ones(size(myds.Observation))` is quite clear to understand, and gets the job done in a line.

Answer (score 1):

it's not elegant but you can also try:

```
myds.Location= myds.Observation*0 + 4;
```